# Calendar validation

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know how to validate calendar, I mean I am getting calendar values from database i.e., Start Date and End Date. when I click on calendar I am able to see before dates and after dates, for example: if I select `27-aug-2015` and `30-aug-2015` I am able to see from `25-aug-2015` to above `30-aug-2015`. I must get only b/w 27th to 30. How do I validate this.

```
<input type="text" id="start" value="<?php echo $this->singlesevasData['startdate'];?>" placeholder="Select Start Date">

<input type="text" id="end" value="<?php echo $this->singlesevasData['enddate'];?>" placeholder="Select End Date">
```

I am using this js file to validate.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEMEURL;?>js/pikaday.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using JS calendar then show your JS function code

Comment: <script>
    var startDate,

        endDate,
        updateStartDate = function() {
            startPicker.setStartRange(startDate);
            endPicker.setStartRange(startDate);
            endPicker.setMinDate(startDate);
        },
        updateEndDate = function() {
            startPicker.setEndRange(endDate);
            startPicker.setMaxDate(endDate);
            endPicker.setEndRange(endDate);
        },

Comment: startPicker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById('start'),
            minDate: new Date(),
            maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
            onSelect: function() {
                startDate = this.getDate();
                updateStartDate();
            }
        }),

Comment: endPicker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById('end'),
            minDate: new Date(),
            maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
            onSelect: function() {
                endDate = this.getDate();
                updateEndDate();
            }
        }),
        _startDate = startPicker.getDate(),
        _endDate = endPicker.getDate();

        if (_startDate) {
            startDate = _startDate;
            updateStartDate();
        }

Comment: if (_endDate) {
            endDate = _endDate;
            updateEndDate();
        }
</script>